# Is there a better way to represent this Sequence Diagram for a Employer-System-Applicant Scenario?

Tags: uml, software-design, sequence-diagram

I've been asked to make a Sequence Diagram for a Casual Employment System in which includes mainly the Applicant, Employer and System. Following my Use Case and Class Diagram, I have used the info I Have to produce a sequence diagram for the Applicant which I have been assigned as actor. My teacher came up with the following comments:

Frames can only be alt, opt or loop.
You can't have multiple arrows into the same activity bar.
It looks like applicant and employer are humans. sequence diagrams are of software not humans. 
There is no method name for the driver method on the left.
There is only one participant for the software "System". You need to have many participants each is a class.

My question would be:
what other participants can I have besides the "system" for the Applicant to interact, what other classes can I make?

[image]

### User Story:

As an applicant, I want to be able to

- create an account so that I can apply/search for available jobs.
- create a job preference so that I can work in my desired field.
- update my employment status.
- change my job preference.
- create and modify my availability regularly so that  my work time will cope with my personal / school schedule.
- add or update my employment records.
- add or update my reference.
- upload my CV online.
- select my interview time, IF I get an invitation to an interview (for shortlisted candidates ONLY).
- accept/reject job offer.
- make a complaint about my employers if necessary.

Comment: Where are your UC and Class diagrams?

Comment: As such your question is just to broad or opinion based since we do not know anything about the system you design. Try to fix the bugs your teacher mentioned and come back with a more detailed question.

Comment: Hello Adarsh, if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, explain what is still not clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to create a class diagram: take the classes in that diagram.

If you know an object-oriented programming language, take the classes you would have in the software.

Otherwise, look at the nouns in the user story: account, job, etc. These will be classes. Some nouns are not classes, but just attributes of classes: desired field, employment status etc. You may ignore these.

All these classes are part of the system. Do not include `System` as a participant.